# Ansible to configure set of hosts which meets specific condition

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have  a use case where I have set of hosts in my inventory file say inventory.txt
as

```
[ios]
a.b.c.d
s.i.s.i
x.x.c.c
```

I need to check if vstack is enabled in each of these hosts, if enabled I need to disable it as a self healing process.

My Playbook :

```
---
- hosts: all

  connection: network_cli

  become: true
  become_method: enable
  tasks:
    - name: Verify whether vstack feature is enabled

      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show vstack config | incl Role
      vars:
        ansible_command_timeout: 30
      register: showvstack

    - debug:
       var: showvstack.stdout
  #   when: showvstack.stdout is regex("'Role.*'")
    #- name: set regex pattern
     # set_fact:
      #  regex_pattern: "^.*Client (SmartInstall enabled).*$"

    - name: Check with when condition
      debug:
        msg: "Vstack Enabled!!!!"
      when: showvstack.stdout | join('') | match('Client (SmartInstall enabled)') or showvstack.stdout | join('') | match('Client')


    - name: If vstack is enabled on switch disable vstack
      ios_config:
       lines:
         - no vstack
      when: showvstack.stdout | join('') | search('Client')

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Play result

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a.b.c.d]
ok: [x.v.b.n]
ok: [z.z.x.c]

TASK [Verify whether vstack feature is enabled] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a.b.c.d]
ok: [x.v.b.n]
ok: [z.z.x.c]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [a.b.c.d] => {
    "showvstack.stdout": [
        "Role: Client (SmartInstall enabled)"
    ]
}
ok: [x.v.b.n] => {
    "showvstack.stdout": [
        "Role: NA"
    ]
}
ok: [z.z.x.c] => {
    "showvstack.stdout": [
        "Role: Client"
    ]
}

TASK [Check with when condition] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [a.b.c.d]
skipping: [x.v.b.n]
skipping: [z.z.x.c]

TASK [If vstack is enabled on switch disable vstack] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [a.b.c.d]
changed: [x.v.b.n]
changed: [z.z.x.c]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
a.b.c.d             : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
x.v.b.n                 : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
z.z.x.c    : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Since some cisco switches gives Role: Client and some cisco switches gives Role: Client Smart Install enabled, the above play will print vstack present even for switch which do not have vstack in it as I am searching for Client and it also takes Role: Client Smartinstall Disabled as Client string is present in it. 
My question is there a better way to print msg saying Vstack is present even when I have a condition saying Role: Client Smartinstall Disabled

Answer (score 0):

Just run the command with the [`when` conditional](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement).

```
tasks
  - name: Run show command
    ios_command: show vstack config | incl Role
    register: showvstack

  - name: disable vstack
    ios_command: # whatever command disables vstack
    when: "'Role: Enabled' in showvstack"
```

It will be skipped when the condition is not met.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have a problem with the string Role:Client as some switches throw output as Role: client some as Role :client (Smartinstall enabled), in that case how do I write an assert statement and based on its output I need to loop the hosts which do not comply and configure using no vstack command

Comment: No idea without seeing actual output of the commands you are running.

Comment: I have added the code and the output and what I am expecting as output